# Is it okay for Unitarians to answer questions that do not ask for a specific denomination or sect?

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to answer the question [What is the biblical support for the Nicene creed's statement of the Son being "eternally begotten"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/54882/what-is-the-biblical-support-for-the-nicene-creeds-statement-of-the-son-being) but I am Unitarian. That means I do not believe there is any biblical support for this, and I would like to explain why. I'm basically asking if this is appropriate for any question that asks for biblical support of something. I understand that I probably will not receive many up-votes, but I'm not really concerned with points anyways. Is this okay with everyone?

Comment: This is essentially the same as your earlier question [Can somebody please help me provide acceptable answers?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6099/can-somebody-please-help-me-provide-acceptable-answers) and my answer is the same.

Comment: Or, you know, answer [questions about Unitarianism when they come along](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/54930/30). Hint hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *personal* convictions are completely irrelevant, but your answers *must match the perspectives asked about*.

If what you want to write disagrees with the premise of the question, you can't post it as an answer.

Sometimes it is appropriate to challenge a question in a comment, such as saying "actually the Catholic Church doesn't believe X, as shown in the Catechism reference Y." But if the question can't be challenged in that way, then there isn't an appropriate venue to post disagreement.

What can you do? Two options: write a new question which aligns with your convictions, or let the question remain unanswered and let the silence speak for you.

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry dannii, I never get to answer questions, so I got a little too excited. I'll delete this.  Thanks for the reminder. I voted for you by the way :)

Comment: Well I can't delete it but I voted to close it

Comment: Uh, are you saying that you can't do a frame challenge in an answer?

Answer (score 6):

> Is this okay with everyone?

No, it is not okay.

Just because it's tagged [biblical-basis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblical-basis) does not exempt answers from following the same scoping rules we do across the site. You may not post a contrary view to whatever doctrine is being questions. Just like a question that asks "What do Catholics believe about X?" must be answered from a Catholic perspective, so also all questions that ask "What is the basis for the belief X?" must be answered from the perspective of belief X. You may not post answers defending Y instead.

All [biblical-basis](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/biblical-basis) questions should be read "What do people that believe X see as the Biblical basis for X?"

Comment: In re your last sentence: how explicitly is that spelled out in the tag description?  I just checked, and It Is Not that clear.  For a new user, it is opaque.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I made an edit to the tag Wiki that addresses your concern. I believe the excerpt is no more clear and how the tag should be used

Comment: @fredsbend Thank you I took a look  As Jon Erickson and others pointed out, that tag as described is a way of saying "sola scriptura" without saying sola scriptura; possibly even "restorationism" or Christian Primitivism.  It is  downright misleading -- bordering on dishonest-- in a plain language reading of the term (biblical basis)  as was discussed over 4 years ago.